# getting an iterator to a generic container inside a generic class: HOW TO

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

This comes from a larger context, however I have stripped alot of code to simplify the question. If you feel I have left anything out please let me know.

Lets say you have a template class defined as:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
template <class key, class container, class container_type>
class file_to_map
{
public:
  file_to_map()
  {
    m_file = "";
  }

  file_to_map(std::string file)
  {
    m_file = file;
  }

  ~file_to_map()
  {
  }

  std::map<key, container>& get_map()
  {
    return m_map;
  }

  void set_file(const std::string file)
  { 
    m_file = file;
  }

  void insert_into_map(key insert, container_type value)
  {
    m_map[insert].insert(value);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, file_to_map<key, container, container_type> &obj)
  {
    typedef typename std::map<key, container>::const_iterator mapItr;
    mapItr mbi = obj.m_map.begin();
    mapItr emi = obj.m_map.end();
    while (mbi != emi) {
      out << " -- " << mbi->first << " -- " << std::endl;
      container::iterator cbi;
      ++mbi;
    }
    return out;
  }

  friend std::istream& operator>> (std::ifstream &in, file_to_map<key, container, container_type> &obj)
  {
    if (in.is_open())
      in.close();

    if (obj.m_file == "")
      return in;

    in.open(obj.m_file.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if (in.fail() || in.bad()) {
      in.close();
      return in;
    }

    std::vector<key> tmp;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<key> string_input;
    copy(string_input(in), string_input(), back_inserter(tmp));
    typename std::vector<key>::iterator bvi = tmp.begin();
    typename std::vector<key>::iterator evi = tmp.end();
    while (bvi != evi) {
      obj.m_map[*(bvi)] = container();
      ++bvi;
    }

    in.close();
    return in;
  }  
  private:
    std::map<key, container> m_map;
    std::string m_file;
};
```

and inside the friend method "`operator<<`"

You want to print the conents of the map and the generic `container` how would one go about doing this? How do you get an appropriate iterator to iterate through the contents of the generic `container`.

I am trying it with:

```
container::iterator cbi;
```

---

**CODE UPDATE**

With:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, file_to_map<key, container, container_type> &obj)
  {
    typedef typename std::map<key, container>::const_iterator mapItr;
    mapItr mbi = obj.m_map.begin();
    mapItr emi = obj.m_map.end();
    while (mbi != emi) {
      out << " -- " << mbi->first << " -- " << std::endl;
      typename container::const_iterator cbi = mbi->second.begin();
      typename container::const_iterator ebi = mbi->second.end();
      std::copy(cbi, mbi, std::ostream_iterator<container_type>(out, "\t\n"));
      ++mbi;
    }
    return out;
  }
```

I am getting the following compiler error:

```
g++ -o file_to_map -Wall ./file_to_map.h ./main.cpp ./code_finder.cpp \
        -L/usr/local/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -I /usr/local/boost_1_48_0/
In file included from ./code_finder.h:4,
                 from ./code_finder.cpp:1:
./file_to_map.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, file_to_map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’:
./code_finder.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./file_to_map.h:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘copy(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, operator<<(std::ostream&, file_to_map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)::mapItr&, std::ostream_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char, std::char_traits<char> >)’
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `typename`:

```
typename container::iterator cbi;
```

Because `iterator` is a dependent name, as it depends on the type argument `container` of the class template. Interestingly, if you've corrected used `typename` in other place, such as in `operator<<`:

```
typedef typename std::map<key, container>::const_iterator mapItr;
```

Since you're working with `const_iterator` for the map which means the *container* objects which you would get using map's const iterator will be `const` objects, which in turn implies you need to use `const_iterator` for the containers as well, because they are the values of the map. So I think you need to use this:

```
typename container::const_iterator cbi; //use this instead!
```

---

Reply to your edit:

I see a typo here:

```
typename container::const_iterator cbi = mbi->second.begin();
typename container::const_iterator ebi = mbi->second.end();
std::copy(cbi, mbi, std::ostream_iterator<container_type>(out, "\t\n"));
            // ^^^ typo
```

The second argument to `std::copy` should be `ebi`, not `mbi`. That is why I usually name such variables as `begin` and `end`, instead of `cbi` and `ebi`.

Comment: That comment helped out quite a bit, however I am still having a few minor probolems. I have added to the post above, would you mind helping me finailzie this?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: Replied to your edit as well. There is a typo in your code.

Comment: That is what I get for a rushed fix right before a daily build =(. Thanks for he help.